# Invert Scrolling in UICollectionView of tvOS

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, tvos

In my tvOS app, I have a UICollectionView.  When I scroll from top to bottom on the Siri Remote, it it moves the view down.  This is the opposite of how most Collection Views would work.  I want it to behave like a trackpad, when you scroll from bottom to top, have it move the collection view down.  How can I invert this scrolling behavior?

Comment: This is pretty standard behavior for the Apple TV. I would not recommend changing the scroll direction in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to move away from Apple TV standards. Your goal in making a tvOS application is not to create an entirely different piece of software, but to make your application feel like an extension of the Apple TV. This creates a better user experience when users open your app and everything behaves just as they expect.