# UITextView scrolling is inverted on tvOS

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, tvos

Okay, weird one here.

I have a UITextView that I am populating with an attributed string. The TextView doesn't want to scroll by itself so I have to enable some settings, specifically:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        articleText.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        articleText.isSelectable = true
        articleText.isScrollEnabled = true
        articleText.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouchType.indirect.rawValue)]
        articleText.bounces = true
        setup()
    }
```

However, setting these cause the scrollView to scroll the inverted way compared to everything else on tvOS. Really bizarre. The full class code is as follows:

```
class ArticleViewController : UIViewController, ListingViewControllerProtocol {

    var listing : ListingData?

    @IBOutlet weak var articleText: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        articleText.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        articleText.isSelectable = true
        articleText.isScrollEnabled = true
        articleText.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouchType.indirect.rawValue)]
        articleText.bounces = true
        setup()
    }

    func setup(){
        if let listing = self.listing {
            APIManager.sharedInstance.getShortendArticle(url: listing.url, onCompletion: { (json) in
                let article = ShortendArticle(fromJson: json)
                let html = "<h1>" + article.title + "</h1>" + article.content

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    let theAttributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: html.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!,
                                                                      options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                                                      documentAttributes: nil)
                    self.articleText.attributedText = theAttributedString
                })
            })

        }
    }
}
```

Mine isn't the same as the related question because I'm not trying to deviate from tvOSs standards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invert Scrolling in UICollectionView of tvOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685150/invert-scrolling-in-uicollectionview-of-tvos)

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be working as expected, it means:

- **Swipe up** gesture scrolls down the text, allowing the user to continue reading more text. Similar behaviour than swiping up in iOS
- **Swipe down** gesture scrolls up the text, allowing going back to the beginning.

From tvOS Human Interface Guidelines:

> On Apple TV, almost everything uses indirect manipulation—gestures
>   move focus between objects, and the system scrolls the interface to
>   keep focused items visible. If your app implements indirect
>   manipulation, make sure focus moves in the direction of the gesture.
>   If someone taps or swipes right on the remote, for example, focus
>   should move right, meaning content may move left. If someone taps or
>   swipes up, focus should move up. Full-screen elements like photos
>   should use direct manipulation instead—gestures move objects, rather
>   than focus. Swiping right, for example, should move the photo from
>   left to right.

https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/user-interaction/

Comment: Is there a particular reason why collectionViews and tableViews work different to this?

Comment: @spogebob92 edited to add mention to Human Interface Guidelines